# Reading a list of numbers from text file into 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, fopen

I'm trying to read numbers from a text file into an array. The text file, "snumbers.txt" has 5 lines with 10 numbers per line all separated by a space:

```
11 10 23 3 23 98 39 12 9 10
10 23 23 23 23 2 2 2 2 2
…etc…
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen("snumbers.txt", "r");

    //read file into array
    int numberArray[100][100];
    int i;



}
```

How do I make it so if I accessed `numberArray[1][1]`, it would give me the number "23".

Comment: Use two `for` loops, the second one being tested under the first one.

Comment: If your sure of input data read accordingly to the array using loops. for(){for(){}}

Comment: Note that your sample input data doesn't seem to tie up with your 5x20 claim.  You show two lines of numbers with 10 numbers in each line.  What is the real data format?  What's the problem with using `fscanf()` to read the numbers?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I said etc... the numbers don't matter and that is what the format looks like without the ""

Comment: The format of the file makes a difference. In particular, it makes a difference to whether you bother checking that there are only 5 lines and that each line has 20 numbers on it, or whether you end up checking that there are at least 5 x 20 = 100 numbers in file and the layout matters not at all, or whether you insist on exactly 100 numbers in the file. There are lots of ways of doing it. Using `fscanf()` means you forgo line checking; using `fgets()` and then `sscanf()` means you can check for the right number of numbers per line. Without precise information from you, we can't help you well.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler okay thanks

Comment: As a matter of curiosity, why are you using a 100x100 array if the file only contains 5 lines with 10 numbers per line?  There could be many good reasons, or it could be what might be regarded as being over-cautious, allocating plenty of space, just in case.  Also, is the 5 x 10 pre-ordained or is it determined at run-time (and if at run-time, how)?  If you might be needing to process 5x10 or 90x80, then the big array makes more sense, as long as there is an upper bound on the size that needs to be processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the complete code that will read your input file into the array. I created a 'converter' that read the characters and convert them to numbers. assuming that you have single space between the numbers. You can use it as is or learn from it so you can implement some solution using this examples:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
  FILE *myFile; // file pointer to read the input file
  int   i,      // helper var , use in the for loop
        n,      // helper var, use to read chars and create numbers
        arr[100][100] , // the 'big' array
        row=0,  // rows in the array
        col,    // columns in the array
        zero=(int)'0';  // helper when converting chars to integers
  char line[512]; // long enough to pickup one line in the input/text file
  myFile=fopen("snumbers.txt","r");
  if (myFile){
        // input file have to have to format of number follow by one not-digit char (like space or comma)
        while(fgets(line,512,myFile)){
                col = 0;        // reset column counter for each row
                n = 0;          // will help in converting digits into decimal number
                for(i=0;i<strlen(line);i++){
                        if(line[i]>='0' && line[i]<='9') n=10*n + (line[i]-zero);
                        else {
                                arr[row][col++]=n;
                                n=0;
                        }
                }
                row++;
        }
        fclose(myFile);

        // we now have a row x col array of integers in the var: arr
        printf("arr[1][1] = %d\n", arr[1][1]); // <-- 23
        printf("arr[0][9] = %d\n", arr[0][9]); // <-- 10
        printf("arr[1][5] = %d\n", arr[1][5]); // <-- 2

  } else {
        printf("Error: unable to open snumbers.txt\n");
        return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm far from convinced that the variable `zero` helps, especially as the range check does not use it.

Comment: the variable zero will hold the value of 48 (ascii for the digit 0), without it the "n=10*n + line[i]" will not work because you will add 48 for a "0", 49 for a "1", etc.

Comment: I'd use `'0'` instead of the variable (which isn't even a `const int`).  The cast is unnecessary; character literals are `int` values.  If you used `if (line[i] >= zero && line[i] <= nine)` (with an appropriate definition: `const int nine = '9';`) then maybe I'd not bother to comment.  However, I think the `if (line[i] >= '0' && line[i] <= '9')` is clear, and the conversion arithmetic could be `n = 10 * n + line[i] - '0';` without loss of clarity — indeed, with a small gain in clarity.